# Sending email in PHP, forcing go to line

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using PHPmailer to send an email. I input my Alt Text (for users with HTML disabled) between double quotes. I'm trying to go to line between sentences and paragraphs but when viewing the email the text all appears on the same line.

How can I go to line in my text based emails sent from PHPmailer?

EDIT:
Didn't think this would be necessary but following comments the code with the alt text is:

```
$alttext =
"
Hello this is the email.

I would like to go to the line. But when this text is printed in the email on the receiver's side it appears all in one line
";

mail->send();
```

I tried using \n, interestingly the \n doesn't appear in the email (it is taken out at some point during the transport) but it doesn't force the text to go to the next line either.

Comment: He means "start a new line" (or maybe paragraph).

Comment: Please post some code showing what you're doing.

Comment: Yes, for example in my post above after the text "appears on the same line." I went to the next line, then the next line again before putting my question.

Comment: `\r\n`? html headers and `<br>`?

Comment: Hey they, I can't use <br> because this is the alt text (for people with HTML disabled in their email clients as I said in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but are you developing on Windows and hosting on Linux?

Windows and Unix/Linux have different ways of handling line breaks. You should use the line break method of your web server.

It may also be possible that the mailer software is removing the line breaks.

Comment: That doesn't matter. It's send in byte form. So it doesn't really care which platform it is. If you send \n it will send \n no matter what.